# Detecting dot11 association packet, etc.

Tags: python

I actually encountered some problem of detection on [Scapy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scapy) and [Python](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Python_%28programming_language%29).
Okay, I started with creating `mon0` by `airmon-ng` after which my I ran my script:

```
if p.haslayer(Dot11AssoReq):  
    print p.sprintf("%Dot11.addr1% | %Dot11Elt.info%")
```

It can work in Ubuntu 12.04 and [BackTrack](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BackTrack) 5r2, but when I run it on Raspberry Pi, it cannot be detected smoothly. How do I fix this problem?

Does the speed matter? Because I been doing some online research and found out that actually Raspberry Pi read Python much slower. I also tried it out and found out that it is much slower compared to Ubuntu which run on my [VMware](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VMware) installation.

Comment: What is it that doesn't work exactly?

Comment: What is Dot11??

Comment: The Raspberry Pi is an educational device, not a high performance computer.  Yes, it will run Python slower than a virtual machine on your desktop, so if you need more processing power you'll have to purchase a faster device instead.